# Adding rows to a database in a one to many mapping (Hibernate/Spring)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, relational-database

EDIT: Still no solution :/

I really need some help with something I have been stuck on for 3 days now. I have a database with two tables, set up like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `restaurant`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `restaurant` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `restaurant_name` TEXT,
  `address` TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `restaurant_table`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `restaurant_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `table_size` int,
  `table_number` int,
  `restaurant_id` int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`restaurant_id`) references `restaurant`(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

There is a one to many mapping between those two tables (as in a Restaurant can have many Tables). I am trying to add a Table into my Restaurant, but can't seem to do that (or sometimes I can't add more than one table).

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction or help me figure out what exactly is wrong in my code. I have expreminted with different cascade options and updateing instead of merging, but never seem to get it working. I think there might be a fundamental fault in my code, maybe the whole way I'm doing it is wrong?

My Restaurant.java file:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="restaurant")
public class Restaurant {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="restaurant_name")
    private String restaurantName;

    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="restaurant")
    private List<RestaurantTable> table = new ArrayList<RestaurantTable>();

    // Getters and setters
```

RestaurantTable.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="restaurant_table")
public class RestaurantTable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="table_size")
    private int tableSize;

    @Column(name="table_number")
    private int tableNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="restaurant_id")
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    // Getters and setters
```

My RestaurantTableController.java:

```
@Controller
public class RestaurantTableController {

    @Autowired
    private RestaurantService restaurantService;

    @Autowired
    private RestaurantTableService restaurantTableService;

    @RequestMapping(value="restaurant/{id}/table", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addRestaurantTable(Model model, @PathVariable Long id) {
        model.addAttribute("table", new RestaurantTable());
        return "newTable";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "restaurant/{id}/table", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addRestaurantTable(@PathVariable Long id, @ModelAttribute ("table") RestaurantTable table) {
        Restaurant restaurant = restaurantService.getRestaurant(id);
        table.setRestaurant(restaurant);
        restaurant.getTable().add(table);
        restaurantService.mergeRestaurant(restaurant);
        return "redirect:/bookings";
    }

}
```

And my mergeRestaurant() method in RestaurantDaoImpl.java:

```
@Override
public void mergeRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.merge(restaurant);
    logger.info("Restaurant record updated successfully, Restaurant Details=" + restaurant);
}
```

The error I get right now is:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity [RestaurantTable#6] are being merged. Detached: [Table number 6]; Detached: [Table number 5]
```

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
Changed

```
private List<RestaurantTable> table = new ArrayList<RestaurantTable>();
```

to

```
private Set<RestaurantTable> table = new HashSet<RestaurantTable>();
```

Also, instead of having "CascadeType.ALL" in Restaurant, I moved it to RestaurantTable.java.

Now, if I try to enter the first Table into the Restaurant it gives me this error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [RestaurantTable#6]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your mapping is correct. Please, don't experiment with it more. One thing: I would like to have a `@ManyToOne` part as lazy one. But it is not necessary, of course.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="restaurant")
public class Restaurant {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="restaurant")
    private List<RestaurantTable> table = new ArrayList<RestaurantTable>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name="restaurant_table")
public class RestaurantTable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="restaurant_id")
    private Restaurant restaurant;

}
```

Looks like, you don't working with a session (or transactions) correctly.

Your `mergeRestaurant()` method looks correct (maybe, I would change `merge()` to `saveOrUpdate()`). So problem is with something other. Try to use another approach.

You associate `RestaurantTable` by a foreign key — to add `RestaurantTable` you don't need to update `Restaurant`. You need only `Restaurant` `id`. Try a more simply method

```
public void addTable(Long restaurantId, RestaurantTable table) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Restaurant restaurant = (Restaurant)session.load(Restaurant.class, restaurantId);
    table.setRestaurant(restaurant);
    session.save(table);
}
```

`session.load()` is used for an optimization, it just returns a proxy with a `restaurantId` without hitting a database. You can even try to use

`table.setRestaurant(new Restaurant(restaurantId));`

It means the same.